# Method with variable arguments followed by non-varargs

Tags: objective-c, methods, syntax, parameters, variadic-functions

I get that you can do something like this:

```
 +(id) objectWithItems: (NSObject *) item, ...;
```

However I was wondering if it was possible to do something like this (I cannot get this to compile):

```
 +(id) objectWithItems: (NSObject *) item, ... withValue:(int)val;
```

So that  I could do:

```
 MyClass *c = [c objectWithItems:a,b,c,nil withValue:5];
```

Is this possible?

I guess I could just invert the parameters...

```
 +(id) objectWithValue:(int) val withItems: (NSObject *) item, ...;
 MyClass *c = [c objectWithValue:5 withItems:a,b,c,nil];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, sorry.  The variadic part of your method signature has to be at the end.

Comment: Seems that way - although works if I invert the parameters in the method.

Comment: Yes, then it's at the end.